# is Kotlin Class<*> equal to Java/Groovy Class<?>

Tags: java, groovy, kotlin

I have a Kotlin function that expects a List of KClass<*>.

I call it from groovy with the following as argument:

`[JvmClassMappingKt.getKotlinClass(Class.forName("some.class"))]`

For some reason the code behaves differently when I call it that way, then when I run it in Kotlin.

Somewhere in the function there is a

```
if(classifier is KClass<*>) { ... }
```

expression. It could be the culprit.

Could it be that a `KClass<*>` not a `Class<?>`?

Comment: No, `KClass` is not a `Class`. But that's what `getKotlinClass` should do: convert a `Class` into a `KClass`. And if your function expects a `List<KClass<*>>`, why is it testing that its elements are actually `KClass`es?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was a different unrelated problem causing this behavior!